# сдвиг данных в ByteBuffer (NIO)

Tags: java

Привет всем, мне нужна помощь с передачей данных через SocketChannel всё вроде работает, но вот данные при получении сдвигаются если ByteBuffer имеет больший размер чем сам массив , как этого избежать при этом не уменьшая буферы.

```
    //Server
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1337));
                SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
                byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };

                while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                while (true) {

                    buf.put(data);
                    buf.flip();
                    socketChannel.write(buf);
                    buf.clear();

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.start();

    //Client
    new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {

                SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
                socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1337));
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

                while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    socketChannel.read(buf);
                    System.out.println(buf.array()[0] + " " + buf.array()[1] + " " + buf.array()[2]);
                    buf.clear();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.start();

}
```

Вывод программы:

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте смотреть. Если читатель перестает читать, то в сокете образуется такая последовательность

```
123|123|123|123|
 1   2   3   4
```

Символ `|` я использовал чисто для визуализации. В сокете идут сплошные байты `123123123123`

Теперь Вы говорите читателю, прочитай мне 4 байта

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
......
socketChannel.read(buf);
```

Он читает. В итоге в буфере оказывается значение

```
1231
```

а в сокете остается

```
23|123|123|
2   3   4
```

После этого Вы выводите три первых байта из буфера

```
System.out.println(buf.array()[0] + " " + buf.array()[1] + " " + buf.array()[2]);
```

Получается `1 2 3` а четвертый байт уничтожаете

```
buf.clear();
```

На следующей итерации Вы опять читаете четыре байта, а выводите три. Итого получается

```
2312    // Буфер
3|123|  // Сокет
3  4
2 3 1  // Вывод
```

На третьей итерации

```
3123     // Буфер
<empty>  // Сокет
3 1 2    // Вывод
```

> как этого избежать

Читайте ровно столько байт, сколько Вам нужно для обработки текущего пакета

Comment: А как быть если клиент заранее не знает сколько байт ему нужно прочитать ? Мне нужно сначала передать число байтов ?

Comment: @Minepolz320 Да. Возможны две версии протокола, либо принимающая сторона знает, сколько нужно прочитать байт (а если не знает, то ей нужно сообщить), либо идет чтение до какого-то разделителя, обозначающего конец сообщения

Comment: Спасибо большое будем думать ;)